# Export fitted values image of harmonic regression NDVI in GEE

Tags: ndvi, regression

I am trying to export rasters of harmonically-regressed fitted values of NDVI for every semi-monthly timestep (twice a month) for a given year. When I visualize the image (mosaic) created using the NDVI fitted values it looks complete (can't see any missing data). But when I export, there are gaps of NoData where there were no Landsat passes during that time period. I thought the harmonic regression had remedied this. Any ideas?

CODE:

```js
//This field contains UNIX time in milliseconds
var timeField = 'system:time_start'

// ----------------- Input user-required info ---------------------------
// Dates should be within Landsat TM range (Aug 22, 1982 to present)
var startdate = ee.Date('2010-01-01');
var enddate = ee.Date('2011-12-31');
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define AOI 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var aoi = ee.Feature(testregion2);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load Landsat imagery 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Define Landsat surface reflectance bands
var sensor_band_dict = ee.Dictionary({
                        l8 : ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,10]),
                        l7 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9]),
                        l5 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9]),
                        l4 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9])  
                        });
// Sensor band names corresponding to selected band numbers                        
var bandNames = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2','pixel_qa']);

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 4 - Data availability Aug 22, 1982 - Dec 14, 1993
var ls4 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l4'), bandNames); 

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 5 - Data availability Jan 1, 1984 - May 5, 2012
var ls5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l5'), bandNames); 

// Landsat 7 data are only used during operational SLC and
// to fill the gap between the end of LS5 and the beginning
// of LS8 data collection

// Prior to SLC-off            
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 7 - Data availability Jan 1, 1999 - Aug 9, 2016
// SLC-off after 31 May 2003
var ls7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR') 
              .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2003-05-31') 
             .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l7'), bandNames);

// Post SLC-off; fill the LS 5 gap
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 7 - Data availability Jan 1, 1999 - Aug 9, 2016
// SLC-off after 31 May 2003
var ls7_2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR') 
              .filterDate('2012-05-05', '2014-04-11') 
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l7'), bandNames);

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 8 - Data availability Apr 11, 2014 - present
var ls8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')  
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l8'), bandNames);

// Merge landsat collections
var l4578 = ee.ImageCollection(ls4
              .merge(ls5)
              .merge(ls7)
              .merge(ls7_2)
              .merge(ls8).sort('system:time_start'))
              .filterDate(startdate, enddate);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mask clouds, cloud shadows, and snow
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ledaps_product_guide.pdf
function maskClouds(img) {
  var qa = img.select(['pixel_qa']);
  var clouds = qa.bitwiseAnd(8).neq(0).or // Cloud shadow (0 = clear, 1 = contamination)
              (qa.bitwiseAnd(16).neq(0)).or // Snow
              (qa.bitwiseAnd(32).neq(0)); // Cloud
  return img.addBands(clouds.rename('clouds')); // Add band of contaminated pixels
}

// Apply mask
var img_masked = l4578.map(maskClouds);

//function to add variables for NDVI, MNDWI, MBSRV, MBSRN, AWESH, time and a constant to imagery

var addVariables = function(image) {
  //compute time in fractional years since the epoch
  var date = ee.Date(image.get(timeField));
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');
  //return image with added bands
  return image
    //add a time band
  .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t'))
  .float()
  //add constant band
  .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1))
  //add NDVI band
  .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red']).rename('NDVI')).toFloat()
};


var filteredLandsat = img_masked
  .filterBounds(testregion1)
  .map(addVariables);
print(filteredLandsat)

// ------------------------------------------------------
// NDVI
// ------------------------------------------------------

//LINEAR MODELLING OF TIME USING ORDINARY LEAST SQUARES

//list of the independent variable names
var independents = ee.List(['constant', 't']);

//name of the dependent variable
var dependent = ee.String('NDVI');

//Compute a linear trend. This will have two bands: 'residuals' and a
// 2x1 band called 'coefficients' (columns are for dependent variables).
var trend = filteredLandsat.select(independents.add(dependent))
.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(independents.length(), 1));

//Map.addLayer(trend, {}, 'trend array image');

//flatten the coefficients into a 2-band image
var coefficients = trend.select('coefficients')
.arrayProject([0])
.arrayFlatten([independents]);


//ESTIMATE SEASONALITY WITH A HARMONIC MODEL

//use these independent variables in the harmonic regression
var harmonicIndependents = ee.List(['constant', 't', 'cos', 'sin']);

//add harmonic terms as new image bands
var harmonicLandsat = filteredLandsat.map(function(image) {
  var timeRadians = image.select('t').multiply(2 * Math.PI);
  return image
  .addBands(timeRadians.cos().rename('cos'))
  .addBands(timeRadians.sin().rename('sin'));
});

var harmonicTrend = harmonicLandsat
  .select(harmonicIndependents.add(dependent))
  //the output of this reducer is a 4x1 array image.
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
    numX: harmonicIndependents.length(),
    numY: 1
  }));

//Turn the array image into a multi-band image of coefficients
var harmonicTrendCoefficients = harmonicTrend.select('coefficients')
  .arrayProject([0])
  .arrayFlatten([harmonicIndependents]);

// Compute fitted values
var fittedHarmonic = harmonicLandsat.map(function(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.select(harmonicIndependents)
      .multiply(harmonicTrendCoefficients)
      .reduce('sum')
      .rename('fitted_ndvi').float());
});



// CREATE NEW COLLECTION WITH SELECTED BANDS AND INDICES

var img_indices = ee.ImageCollection(fittedHarmonic.select('fitted_ndvi'));

// rename bands

function renameBands(image) {
  var bands = ['fitted_ndvi'];
  var new_bands = ['ndvi'];
  return image.select(bands).rename(new_bands);
}

var img_indices = img_indices.map(renameBands)



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculate hillshade mask
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function addHillshade(img) {
    var solar_azimuth = img.get('SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE');
    var solar_zenith = img.get('SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'); // solar altitude = 90-zenith
    var solar_altitude = ee.Number(90).subtract(ee.Number(solar_zenith));
   return img.addBands(ee.Terrain.hillshade(dem, solar_azimuth, solar_altitude).rename('hillshade').float()); 
}

// Add hillshade bands
var img_indices = img_indices.map(addHillshade);
print(img_indices)



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Produce NDVI mosaic
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-04-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-04-30');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-05-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-05-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-05-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-05-31');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-06-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-06-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-06-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-06-30');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-07-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-07-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-07-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-07-31');

var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-08-01');
var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-08-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-08-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-08-31');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-09-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-09-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-09-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-09-30');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-10-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-10-15');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-10-16');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-10-31');

// var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-11-01');
// var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-11-15');
var ndvi_mosaic = img_indices.select('ndvi').filterDate(mosaicstart,mosaicend).mosaic().clip(aoi);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Visualization of NDVI Image Products
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Center on polgon
Map.centerObject(eponds, 16);


// Viz parameters: classes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
var ndvi_viz = {min:-1, max: 1, palette: ['000000', '002ba1', '6287ec', '77b800', 'c1bdb6']};
var ls_viz =  {bands: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue'], min:0, max:3000, gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]};

var landsatMosaic = filteredLandsat.filterDate(mosaicstart, mosaicend).mosaic()

Map.addLayer(landsatMosaic, ls_viz, 'Landsat')
// NDVI
Map.addLayer(ndvi_mosaic, ndvi_viz, 'ndvi mosaic', true);


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Export image
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Using crs and crsTransform rather than scale is recommended for aligning Landsat pixels <-- having trouble with this
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: ndvi_mosaic, 
    // description: '2011Apr16_30',
    // description: '2011May01_15',
    // description: '2011May16_31',
    // description: '2011Jun01_15',
    // description: '2011Jun16_30',
    // description: '2011Jul01_15',
    // description: '2011Jul16_31',
    description: '2011Aug01_15_d',
    // description: '2011Aug16_31',
    // description: '2011Sep01_15',
    // description: '2011Sep16_30',
    // description: '2011Oct01_15',
    // description: '2011Oct16_31',
    // description: '2011Nov01_15',
    folder: 'TestRegion2_NDVI',
    scale: 30,
    //crs: 'EPSG:5070',  // 5070 = USGS Albers Equal Area Conic
    //crsTransform: [30, 0, -2214330, 0, -30, 2091360], // 5070-specific transform
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: aoi  //for complex areas: aoi.geometry().bounds(),
  });
```

Comment: Can you please share the Code Editor script link. The code chuck above is missing imports.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b060e858d5d66d8d1788447d87376141

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the harmonic regression works, but you may need to fill in empty overpass periods with a dummy masked image in order for the missing date(s) to be interpolated. Here is a script that shows what periods are missing images and how to fill them in with a masked dummy. It is for demo purposes, you'll need to modify it to actually try it with your application. 

https://code.earthengine.google.com/86af5f92b789645bdea6c1bcde1e1fbb

This seems like a really useful operation, will you let me know if you get it to work.

Comment: Hi jdbcode. It seems your solution will work. But unfortunately my GEE coding skills are inadequate to completely implement your solution using your preliminary code. Can you please provide more complete code? Thank you!